# Transfer Notes and Attachments from One Object to Another

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, contentversion, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink

need help figuring our my batch job that moves Notes and Attachments from one object(dsfs__DocuSign_Status__c), to its related Account, then delete the notes and attachments after they are moved. I just don't fully understand the relationship between ContentDocumentLink, ContentDocument. Here is my code...

The scheduler here is fine, I don't think anything is wrong here...

Scheduler

```
global class scheduleNotesAttachTransfer implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext SC){
        //NotesAttachTransfer.NotesAttach();
        NotesAttachTransfer nat = new NotesAttachTransfer();
        Id batchId = Database.executeBatch(nat);
    }
    Public static void SchedulerMethod(){
        String timeinterval = '0 5 * * * ?';
        System.schedule('Batch Transfer of Notes and Attachments every 5 min', timeinterval, new 
     ScheduleNotesAttachTransfer());
    }
}
```

The job is where I think I am having issues. As you see in the QueryLocator I want to fine all the notes and attachments to a dsfs__DocuSign_Status__c object record, because I want to move the notes and attachments to the account object. I believe that I am not correctly querying those objects? and that In my execute method nothing is being passed through or assigned correctly.

Job

```
global class NotesAttachTransfer implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {
    global Integer recordsProcessed = 0;
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        List<dsfs__DocuSign_Status__c> DS = [Select Id from dsfs__DocuSign_Status__c];
        Set<Id> Ids = new Set<Id>();
        for(dsfs__DocuSign_Status__c d : DS){
            Ids.add(d.Id);
        }   
        return Database.getQueryLocator(
            'SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId IN:Ids'
        );
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<ContentDocumentLink> attachList){
        // process each batch of records
        Set<Id> DSIds = new set<Id>();
        for(ContentDocumentLink a:attachList){
            DSIds.add(a.LinkedEntityId);
        }
        List<Account> accList = [Select Id from Account where DocuSign_Status__c IN: DSIds];

        List<ContentDocumentLink> attachList2 = new List<ContentDocumentLink>();
        for(Account acc:accList){
            for(ContentDocumentLink aa : attachList){
                for(Integer i=0; i < attachList.size(); i++){
                    if(acc.DocuSign_Status__c==aa.LinkedEntityId){
                    ContentDocumentLink att = new ContentDocumentLink();
                    att.Id = acc.Id;
                    attachList2.add(att);
                    recordsProcessed = recordsProcessed + 1;
                    }
                }
            }            
        }
        insert attachList2;
        delete attachList;
    }    
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        // execute any post-processing operations
        System.debug(recordsProcessed + ' records processed.');
        AsyncApexJob job = [SELECT Id, Status, NumberOfErrors, 
            JobItemsProcessed,
            TotalJobItems, CreatedBy.Email
            FROM AsyncApexJob
            WHERE Id = :bc.getJobId()];
        System.debug(job);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Please edit your post to describe more fully what you are trying to understand and what specific issues you are having.

Comment: To echo what David said, it'd be helpful to [edit] and explain what is not working and what you expected/wanted to happen instead.

Comment: Thanks I made some updates, hopefully it makes a bit more sense!

Comment: I would try formatting the bind variables in your query like so `IN :Ids` and then adding some debug statements to see if your lists have any data.